git reorganize pull request (e.g. into one commit per file)
I'm working on a project where I have a pull-request of another contributor that contains quite a number of commits (>15), some with really minor changes. In essence, the pull-request boils down to changes on only three files, and the cumulative changes could easily be contained in one commit per file. I like the changes, but I don't want to clutter our repo with an unnecessary high amount of commits and I am tempted to squash the whole pull request, but that again I feel would be too coarse of a change history.
Is it possible to completely rewrite the pull-request to three commits, one for each file? Or simply accept only changes to certain files done by that pull-request, squashing the pull request first to commits for file 1, the again for commits for file 2 and a third time for commits for file 3?
Disclaimer: I am not that experienced with pull requests yet, this question might seem naive to some. I figure the "granularity" of commits is a question of style, but seeing that it can play quite a big role in terms of "rewinding", cherry-picking and/or simply reconstructing what has changed, I find it is worth spending the time to ensure a "clean and readable" commit history.

This is regret type 2. This is also the method spelled out in larsks' answer.


Is it possible to completely rewrite the pull-request to three commits, one for each file?

Sure, although it's worth noting that this question really isn't about pull requests; it's just a question about rewriting your commit history in git.
Reset you feature branch to the base branch (I'm assuming main for the purpose of this example):
git reset main

Now commit the changes in file1:
git add file1
git commit -m 'These are the changes in file1'

And then repeat that for file2 and file3:
git add file2
git commit -m 'These are the changes in file2'
git add file3
git commit -m 'These are the changes in file3'

Now force-push your changes to your remote to update the pull request:
git push -f

As always, operate on a new branch or a copy of your repository if you are unsure that this will do what  you want.

Thank you! Just to make sure I understood this right: I would first accept the pull request onto my feature branch (or redirect it to a new isolated branch) and then rewrite it's history using this method (and optionally create a new pull request for the branch for it to go to the branch that it is intended for).

I may be confused, but I thought this was your pull request, so you would already have the changes locally: no need to "accept" the pull request, right? If that's not the case, then sure, your comment makes sense. Regarding the latter part of your comment, in most cases, I would not suggest creating a new pull request; it's generally better to update the existing one (but that's just my preference, and your team may have different policies).

Sorry, my question wasn't clear in that regard. The pull request is from someone else, currently I am the only core committer of this repository and others are working on their forks and contribute via pull requests that I have to manage and "harmonize" to the commit style I want. Thank you for clarifying :)

A note: this sequence is useful enough that there's a short option for it: git reset main; git commit -om'file 1 msg' file1; git commit -om'file 2 msg' file2; git commit -om'file3 msg' file3. --only aka -o: ignore the index and make a commit with only listed paths updated, to their current work tree contents.
